# how to config nginx to redirect to a specified uri after login

Tags: nginx

I configured my Nginx server's error_page to a specified Uri in this way:

```
  location /protected {
        auth_request /checkauth/protected;
        alias /home/stone/protected;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        error_page 401 /login;
  }
```

this works perfectly for redirecting the unauthorized user to **/login** page.
But, what's next? I want my user to redirect to their origin Uri after they logged on **/login** page.

How to achieve this? should I pass some parameters to the error_page, and how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out myself. as the Nginx server is using [**internal redirection**](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html) for error_page. What I just need to do is reload that page again.

```
window.location.reload()
```